# Does George Costanza have a brother?

Tags: character, seinfeld

In two separate episodes of Seinfeld, George mentions his brother.

The first, in episode fifteen of the third season, titled "The Suicide":

> **RULA:** Who’s Pauline?
>   
> **GEORGE:** Pauline? . . . Wait a minute. I got it. My brother once impregnated a woman named Pauline.
>   
> **RULA:** Do you think about her?
>   
> **GEORGE:** When I hear her name mentioned.

The second, in the twenty-third episode of the third season, titled "The Parking Spot":

> **ELAINE:** Oh come on, George, please put it in a garage. I don't want to spend
>   an hour looking for a space.
>   
> **GEORGE:** I can't park in a garage.
>   
> **ELAINE:** Why?
>   
> **GEORGE:** I don't know, I just can't. Nobody in my family can pay for parking,
>   it's a sickness. My father never paid for parking; my mother, my brother,
>   nobody. We can't do it.

Further confusing the situation is that in later episodes George repeatedly claims to be an only child. (examples welcome)

< seinfeldvoice >
***So what's the deal with George Constanza's brother? Is he real, or is George an only child?***
< / seinfeldvoice >

Comment: I love how I read everything in the respective character's voices

Comment: Haha same! Those voices are tattooed into the ol' brain basket.

Comment: Also, both Jerry & Elaine have sisters that were mentioned once (in *The Chinese Restaurant* & *The Pick*, respectively) and IIRC never again. Seems the show just chose to ignore siblings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately it is an unsolved mystery; those are the only 2 times his brother is mentioned and there is much more of him claiming otherwise.

- It could only be a common "movie" mistake, since there is not any weight
  put on his brother he is only used as a subject in a response.
- In other case it could only be that his is just sarcastic when
  telling he is only child, like he has a grunge against his brother.

I would go with a "movie" mistake however.

Answer (score -6):

George's brother, several years older than George, could not take the insanity and
left home at 18, never to be heard from again.

Comment: Could you back your claims somehoe in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

Comment: There is no answer given during the series. I was just speculating. Would like to hear other speculations based on what we know about the Costanza family

Comment: Well, first of all, if that's the case you should point out that you#re just speculating. But in this case ti would also tremendously help the answer to include your reasoning and any evidence or deduction for *why* you speculated this.

Comment: I inferred that George's brother is older from the comment he made about his Father, Mother and Brother never paid for parking.  His leaving, never to return to the Costanza family asylum speaks for itself.

Comment: You might want to [edit] those points into the actual answer.

Comment: Despite the down-votes, that's a good speculation.    I'll see your speculation and raise you one.    It was something they considered revisiting, (like Kramer's mother), but they fell in love with Lloyd Braun and felt that was the way to go instead of an older brother.   I'll have to check his first episode and see if the timing works.